# Intuitive explanation of local derivative pattern (LDP)?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction, local-features

Zhang et al. proposed the LDPs for face recognition . They considered the LBP as the nondirectional first-order local pattern operator and extended it to higher orders ( th-order) called the LDP.

- is there an intuitive explanation of this definition? i need your help.

Comment: can you attach a link to that paper please